# Entity Framework Include() : A specified Include path is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following Entity Framework statement that has been working correctly.

```
CostingEvent targetEvent = repository.Query<CostingEvent>()
                                     .FirstOrDefault(ce => ce.Id == targetId);
```

However, I needed to disable lazy loading for this code and so I've added an `Include()` element to the previous statement:

```
CostingEvent targetEvent = repository.Query<CostingEvent>()
                                     .Include(ce => ce.ProposalSection.Proposal.Costing)
                                     .FirstOrDefault(ce => ce.Id == targetId);
```

However, this generates a run-time exception:

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Leo.Domain.CostingEvent' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Costing'.

I really don't understand this error. First of all, I am not referencing `CostingEvent.Costing`, I'm referencing `CostingEvent.ProposalSection.Proposal.Costing`. Furthermore, these are all valid navigation properties that show up in Intellisense.

*Note: This is a database-first application. Also note: `repository` is a wrapper class but the `Include()` reference is standard Entity Framework.*

Comment: And I assume that all properties are mapped?

Comment: Could you provide a gist with the corresponding classes? This should work as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested EF Includes are tricky.

Have you considered

```
CostingEvent targetEvent = repository.Query<CostingEvent>()
                                .Include("ProposalSection.Proposal.Costing")
                                .FirstOrDefault(ce => ce.Id == targetId);
```

This may also work

```
CostingEvent targetEvent = repository.Query<CostingEvent>()
                                .Include(ce => ce.ProposalSection)
                                .Include(ce => ce.ProposalSection.Proposal)
                                .Include(ce => ce.ProposalSection.Proposal.Costing)
                                .FirstOrDefault(ce => ce.Id == targetId);
```

Comment: I saw that syntax is supported, but I do not understand why it would be different.

Comment: It's not different, and the third Include is all you need (it implies the previous two).

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the subnavigation properties like this:

```
CostingEvent targetEvent = repository.Query<CostingEvent>()
                                     .Include(ce => ce.ProposalSection.Select(ps=>ps.Proposal.Select(p=>p.Costing)))
                                     .FirstOrDefault(ce => ce.Id == targetId);
```

Comment: Doesn't `Select()` require a collection on the left of the dot? `ProposalSection` and `Proposal` are all singulars.

Comment: Yes, select usually does require a collection on the left.  Is Costing a navigation property or just a property of Proposal?  If Costing is just a regular property, then you don't need to have it, just end with Proposal.